# Win 10: Disable "Restoring Network Connections" popup when connection to network drives drop

Tags: networking, windows-10, connection

[image: error message pic]

Whenever I get disconnected from my network drives and I happen to have like 10 folders of the network drive folders opened, 10 of these pop-ups will show up and I cannot close any of the windows unless I manually click on OK on every popup. Could I disable this error message somehow?

Comment: Annoying the window appears to be part of `explorer.exe` and doesn't appear in `tasklist /V | find /i "Restoring"`.

Comment: I know this question is 2 year old, but I just wish these could be a toast notification and not a modal dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I found a [guide](https://www.technipages.com/windows-disable-windows-cannot-connect-to-all-network-drives) that I sadly cannot follow without admin rights.

But in short:

- Open the Registry Editor
- Navigate to: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\NetworkProvider
- Create a "DWORD Value" called RestoreConnection and set the value to 0 (or change value if it already exists)

Comment: I assume this will disable restore connection, not just the error message. I wonder about the consequence of this? Maybe none, time will tell :-/

Comment: I would expect the value should be `1` for NOT restoring connection. I assume `0` is default (and `0` didn't change anything for me). I'll give `1` a try.

Comment: For me, neither '1' nor '0' changed the behaviour, when disconnecting my VPN I got the usual behaviour with an error message about network drives being no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

Happens to me all the time.

I use [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com) quite often, so I wrote this script and run it every time these messages pop up.

```
wintitle:="Restoring Network Connections"
Loop {
    if (WinExist(wintitle))
    {   
        WinActivate, %wintitle%
        WinWaitActive, %wintitle%,,3
        Send, {Return}
        Sleep, 200
    }
    else
    {
        ExitApp, 0
        Return
    }
}
```

It cycles through these windows and presses Enter on each to close them.